# How to using OpenId in joomla 2.5 or 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

In joomla 1.5 have a plugin `Authentication - Openid`, but in joomla 2.5, this plugin not see, How to config Open id in joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using [OneAll Social Login](http://docs.oneall.com/plugins/guide/social-login-joomla/)

Answer (score 0):

OneAll needs registration to a third party service :[